# How to change timestamp and nonce in Requests-OAuthlib?

Tags: python, oauth, timestamp, nonce

I am trying to get some data from upwork's api.
I am using [Requests-OAuthlib](http://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) .For one API request it works but for second one I get this error: "**Duplicate timestamp/nonce combination, possible replay attack. Request rejected.**"
 So I tried to modify Requests-OAuthlib and change timestamp and nonce manually by putting this inside constructor:

```
        ur = u''+str(SystemRandom().random())
        ur = ur.replace("0.","")
        self.client.nonce = ur
        ts = u'' + str(int(time()))
        self.client.timestamp = ts
```

right after self.client = client_class( ...
But it still does not work.
I am a complete beginner on both python and OAuth so I would rather use this library instead of building the request url manually.

Here's the source code of the library [Requests-OAuthlib source code](https://github.com/requests/requests-oauthlib/blob/master/requests_oauthlib/oauth1_auth.py)

If I print them at the end of **call** they have the same values as the ones I set but setting them doesn't seem to have an effect , upwork still says replay attack.
Also I tried putting them in headers, still not working

```
r.headers['oauth_nonce'] = ur
r.headers['oauth_timestamp'] = ts
```

**Update:**
I printed r.headers and it containes these:

for first call

```
oauth_nonce="55156586115444478931487605669", oauth_timestamp="1487605669"
```

for second call

```
oauth_nonce="117844793977954758411487605670", oauth_timestamp="1487605670"
```

Nonces and timestamps are **different from one another**. So why is upwork giving me : "Duplicate timestamp/nonce combination, possible replay attack. Request rejected." ?

**Update2:** Probably it's just some crazy upwork behaviour, still waiting for an answer from them. I believe that because if I change something in the endpoint it's working, so nonces/timestamps seem unrelated to the problem.

**Update3:** I got an answer from upwork. Sincerly I can't understand the answer but if you consider it makes sense you can close the question. I found a workaround anyway.
https://community.upwork.com/t5/API-Questions-Answers/Wrong-API-error-message/td-p/306489

Comment: What have you did to work around this Duplicate timestamp/nonce combination, possible replay attack. Request rejected. error?

Comment: sorry , I can't remember , it was a one time job a long time ago, I don't work much with OAuth

Answer (score 2):

For anyone coming across this issue, I was banging my head against it for a few hours until I finally used Fiddler to look at the requests and responses.

The server was responding with a 302 redirect, and my http library was helpfully following the redirect and sending the same headers - which of course included the duplicate nonce and timestamp.